# GPG decrypting/encrypting string in memory only

Tags: unix, gnupg, cat, password-encryption

**Background:**

I have a GPG encrypted secret that must not be written to file unencrypted.
Let say that it lives at `~/.secrets/.mysecret.gpg`.

Running `gpg ~/.secrets/.mysecret.gpg` unencrypts the `.mysecret.gpg` and saves it to file at `.mysecret` (unacceptable). Running `gpg -d ~/.secrets/.mysecret.gpg` prints the decrypted secret only (thank you `JustinC`).

To avoid the stderr and to encode it in base64 for my use purpose, I wrote this shell function as a convenience method:

```sh
keyreader() {
  local gpg_file=$1
  echo -n "$(gpg -d "$gpg_file" 2> /dev/null)" | base64
}
```

Running `keyreader ~/.secrets/.mysecret.gpg`, after entering the password for the encrypted secret, it prints out the base64 encoded, decrypted secret, no output file.

**Questions:**

1. When `gpg -d ~/.secrets/.mysecret.gpg` is run, does gpg write a tmp file that would include the unencrypted `.mysecret`?
2. Why does gpg not output a file, `.mysecret`, when I use the above syntax? (ANSWER: the `-d` flag was used, again thank you `JustinC`).
3. Assuming I use the appropriate `$HISTIGNORE` identifier before running the command, how can I encrypt a string from the command line to a .gpg AES256 encrypted file without having first written it unencrypted to file?

For Q3, something like:

`$ echo "secret info" | gpg --cipher-algo AES265 -c -o secrets_file.txt.gpg`

instead of:

`$gpg --cipher-algo AES265 -c secrets_file.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Again, @JustinC, thank you for your answer.

For completeness, here is my solution for encrypting/decrypting a string in memory only:

### encryption:

```sh
# notice the space before echo here
# it is the default $HISTIGNORE flag which can be set in the ~/.bashrc
# it keeps this line from being written to the ~/.bash_history file

 echo -n 'your secrets here' | gpg -c > ~/.secrets/.mysecret.gpg

# Enter passphrase:
```

### decryption:

```sh
# 2> /dev/null: skip printing strerr

gpg -d ~/.secrets/.mysecrets.gpg 2> /dev/null
```

NB: If you get the error "inappropriate ioctl for device", you may be running on WSL and this may help you:

```sh
# https://d.sb/2016/11/gpg-inappropriate-ioctl-for-device-errors

echo -e "use-agent\npinentry-mode loopback" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf
echo "allow-loopback-pinentry" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure `gpg -d ~/.secrets/.mysecret.gpg` writes decrypted file to disk? It does not for me.

1. You can use strace to check if any temporal file is created.
2. I sometimes prevent leaving password in bash history by typing:

```
PP=`cat`
secret-info ENTER Ctrl+D
echo $PP  # will print "secret-info"
```

The secret-info string is sent to cat program, not to shell, so bash will not save it to history file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I realized that I was not passing the `-d` flag when I was testing and that is why it wrote to disk the unencrypted file. I realized that the encryption of the string issue was being caused by not having gpg configured correctly (because I'm using WSL). [This blog](https://d.sb/2016/11/gpg-inappropriate-ioctl-for-device-errors) gives info about this configuration for other having the same issue. I edited my question to reflect your comments. Very cool cat trick by the way!